# How say to python that (a+b) = (b+a) and (a*b) = (b*a)

Tags: python, list, operators

I have all possible combinations of operations between numbers in a list:

```
list = ['2','7','8']

7+8*2
8+7*2
2*8+7
2+8*7
2-8*7
8-2/7
etc
```

I want to know if it's possible to say that operations like ('7*2+8' and '8+7*2' and '2*7+8') or (7*8*2 and 2*8*7 and 7*2*8) etc. are the same. I want to know how take only one operation if it's the same operation.

This is my code to create these different operations:

```
Op = ['+','-','*','/']
array = []
for i in Op:
    array.append(string1 + i + string2)
    return array
```

Comment: Python doesn't know.  You will need to implement such logic yourself to flag `+` and `*` as commutative operations, parse the expressions into a *canonical* form, and remove duplicates.  Also, 7+8*2 being the same as 8+7*2 is true only if you ignore normal order of operations.

Comment: In what sense are the "the same"?  The are different strings; evaluated as mathematical expressions, they produce different values.  You need to determine your definition of "same" and write code to recognize those properties.  There is no general way.  You seem to be asking about designing a function to take some input expressions and return a Boolean value.  Both teaching you how to do that design, and teaching you how to write the function, are out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could implement additional rules like "numbers in sums and products must be sorted in increasing order" to at least reduce the number of "same" terms.

Comment: Make no possible combination with same numbers for [ + * ] .

Answer (score 2):

if I understand you well, I think I have an idea for you.

First of all, you need to create all of the possible permutations of digits and expressions. You can do that in this way:

```
import itertools
num_list = ['2','7','8']
op = ['+','-','*','/'] * 2 # *2 for the case of same operator twice

num_perm = list(itertools.permutations(num_list))
op_perm = list(itertools.permutations(op, 2)) # We want perm of two operators.
```

Now, you need to merge all the permutation to a math expression, this is a nice way for that:

```
list_of_experssions = list()
for num in num_perm :
    for op in op_perm:
        list_of_experssions.append(num[0] + op[0] + num[1] + op[1] +num[2])
```

The last step is to check if the results of the two expressions are equal (using `eval` function) but the expressions themself are different:

```
for exp1 in list_of_experssions:
    for exp2 in list_of_experssions:
        if eval(exp1) == eval(exp2) and exp1 != exp2:
            print(exp1, exp2)
```

In your case, we got 336 math expressions and 2560 couples of equal expressions.

Comment: We can prevent here : 
`list_of_experssions.append(num[0] + op[0] + num[1] + op[1] +num[2])` to avoid another loop.

Comment: I added a comment at your post

Comment: @mario_nsport - I fixed the bug.

Comment: If it works, you can approve this answer by click on the green V sign. ;)

Comment: I am afraid this method has one problem: it will, for example, consider `7-8/2` and `2+8-7` "duplicates", as they evaluate to the same value (3), even though the difference between them is **not** just a matter of commutative operations.